# Does Lightroom 3 support multipage TIFF?

Tags: lightroom, tiff

After scanning a series of negatives, I ended up with a large multipage TIFF file. Apparently Lightroom (I have ver. 3.6) only recognize the first image. Is there a way to handle multipage TIFF directly from Lightroom?

Edit: I have found the following [question on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/q/44600/15425) which is not exactly promising...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) to convert the tiff to multiple files then they will open fine in Lightroom

```
convert multipage.tif single%d.tif
```

Comment: Sorry @Rob, for some reason I had missed your reply. In the meanwhile, I had already decided for the "ImageMagick route".

Comment: No problem - so is this the correct answer?

Comment: It is the best solution that I found until now, so it answers indirectly the question about LR support.